# A RenderFlex overflowed by 330 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

```dart
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
          color: const Color(0xFF722a8c),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        "COLORS ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: const Icon(
                                Icons.check,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFFf44136),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF2295f6),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFF4daf52),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "CLEAR ALL ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  border:
                                      Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                                ),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.clear,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "ERASER",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                        child: Row(children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/icon.png',
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      )
                    ]),
                Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "UNDO ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                ),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.undo,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 45,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "REDO ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100),
                        child: Row(children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: 40,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              child: const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.redo,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 50,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      )
                    ]),
                Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          "SAVE",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  border:
                                      Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                                ),
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.check,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: Text(
                          "DO NOT SAVE",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 28,
                        ),
                        child: Row(children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: 10,
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                                child: const Text(
                              "Cancel",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      )
                    ]),
              ]),
            ],
          )),
    );
```

Comment: Don't try to bypass the system by pasting code-text. Describe the method you've tried. What issue you've faced, and what are you trying to archive?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As for inner row's children, there will different screen-size devices. While you've used `Row` you can make it `horizontal` scrollable by wrapping `Row` with a scrollable widget like `ListView`. For theses few buttons, we can use `SingleChildScrollView`

```dart
body: Container(
    height: 100,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: const Color(0xFF722a8c),
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, ///make sure to use horizontal
          child: Row(children: [
            Column(
```

Also you can try [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html), or [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) (+with builder) widgets.